# Confusion from Griffith's book

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, dielectric

In Griffith's Electrodynamics (Third Ed.), on page no. $176$, it is written:

> It may have appeared to you that I left out the surface bound chrage
>   $\sigma_b$ in deriving Eq. 4.22, and in a sense that is true. We
>   cannot apply Gauss's law precisely *at* the surface of a dielectric
>   sphere, for here $\rho_b$ blows up, taking the divergence of
>   $\mathbf{E}$ with it. But everywhere *else* the logic is sound, and in
>   fact it we picture the edge of the dielectric as having some finite
>   thickness within which the $\color{red}{\mathrm{polarization\,\,tapers\,\, off \,\,to\,\,zero}}$ (probably a
>   more realistic model [...]

My question is what does it mean by **"the polarization tapers off to zero"**?

Comment: Kindly consider quoting the paragraph as text. The readability under the "highlighter" is very poor.

Comment: Even *without* highlighter, scans of text (or math) are never appropriate on this site. They aren’t searchable, and they aren’t accessible to visually-impaired members. Please remove the scan and type the text.

Answer (score 0):

The usual assumption in this kind of problems (i.e. find $\mathbf{E}$ or $\mathbf{B}$ from a certain charge or coil geometry) is the following: 
 you are dealing with *localised* charges and currents.

It's a *finite* sphere. So, for the volume integral, you don't have to integrate over *all* of space. Just over the physical extent of the charge in question. 
 If there is a surface term, this is evaluated at $r\rightarrow \infty$ where the electric/magnetic field from your localised (i.e. finite extent) charge is zero.

This assumption is **not true** when you have infinite sheets, wires, etc. But these are not as "realistic", to use the same word of that paragraph.